# How to make sure users can only vote once per post

Tags: php, mysql, restrictions, voting-system

I'm building a website which has a feature which ressembles SE's voting system. I'm trying to restrict users from voting more than once per post.

Currently, I was thinking of having a field in my `user` mysql database that would keep a list of `id`s (corresponding to posts) that the user has already voted on. Each time the user casts a vote, the array is checked against the current post's `id`. If it is found an error message is displayed, if not the vote goes through and the `id` is now part of the user's "already voted on" list.

This seems like an odd way of doing this. Is it an efficient method? What method would be better/best?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would create a separate table called user_post that would have the user_id and post_id - in fact, you can make those columns a multi-column primary key.

When a user votes on a post, you can use the following query:

```
REPLACE INTO user_post (user_id, post_id, vote) VALUES (:userId, :postId, :vote)
```

Replace is essentially saying 'insert unless there is a unique key conflict, if so, update the row'.  Or, you can use:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO user_post (user_id, post_id, vote) VALUES (:userId, :postId, :vote)
```

which essentially says 'insert unless there is a unique key conflict, if so, ignore' (if you only want to keep the first vote).